# {exp:playa:parents} returning value of {exp:channel:entries} that it's nested within

Tags: add-on, playa, pixelandtonic

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    {exp:playa:parents}
        {title} returns title from the entry
    {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If I remove the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pair, then the playa returns the correct data. However, I need info from the entry and then I want to loop through all the parents in another channel.

In this case, think of the entry as a product, and then return all the FAQs about that product. The relationship is made on the FAQ not the product.

Comment: Definitely should not be the case. This works for me all the time. Can you try adding a `channel` parameter to your `playa:parents` tag?

Comment: I've done it before too and thought it was strange I couldn't get the proper entries out.

There is, I just simplified for the post.

`{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1" url_title="{last_segment}"}`

`{exp:playa:parents channel="faqs"}`

Comment: Is that your full template code? also, what is your version of EE and Playa?

Comment: I've tried stripping it down to just that with no luck. I'm on latest of everything. I was able to get the `{exp:playa:parents}` tag to return the correct number of entries by adding `child_id="{entry_id}"` to the tag pair (still with in channel entries loop), however it is still returning the title from the channel:entries loop. `{parent:title}` and `{child:title}` return as strings not as the variable.

Comment: Ryan - I missed your response on this a month ago! I'm so sorry. Did you still need help with this one?

Comment: In this particular case, I got frustrated and just wrote manual query. But believe I have it sorted out in additional places with var_prefix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like, although it's not entirely clear how your relationship is defined, is that you're just coming at it from the wrong end of the relationship. If the entry is a ***product*** and the relationship is defined in this entry to FAQ pages then you need to be calling the ***children*** of this entry rather than the ***parent***.

> **Parent**: The entry that has the Playa field.
>
> **Child**: The entry that you selected in the Playa field.

Have you tried `{exp:playa:children}` instead of parent?

Comment: It's the opposite of how you explained it. The relationship is made in the FAQ. I'm looping through the products, then want to loop through the the parent FAQs. But to answer your question, I did try the `{exp:playa:children}` for shoots and ladders - no dice.

Comment: And for the record, changing from parents to children still returns the same value; which is the channel:entries data.

Comment: OK that clears up the relationship a bit. So if the FAQs are the parent and the Products are the children then I'd say that you need to be using `{exp:channel:entries channel="faqs"}` for the Channel Entries tag (the parent). Then `{exp:playa:parents channel="products"}` for the children?

Comment: I'm 99% sure I have the tags *right* just not sure why it's not returning the right data - I suppose I'll just embed a template.

I should be able to loop through the products, all their data, and then have a list of the parent Playa entries. (I tried the method you suggested with out success)

Comment: What's strange is that if I run `{exp:playa:total_parents}`, it returns 8 - it should return 1 according to the DB. Where parent_entry_id = this entry, it has 1 child.